# Modifying JSON element of type "dynamic"

Tags: c#, reflection, json.net

I am trying to deserialize some JSON data, make a modification to a small part of the data, and re-serialize back into JSON format.

The JSON data looks something like this:

```json
{
    "name": "...",
    "type": "...",
    "values": [0, 1, "apple", ...],
    ...
}
```

`values` is a mixed-type array with an unknown number of elements, and as such I use the `dynamic` type for its C# model:

```cs
public class Model
{
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public String Type { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("values")]
    public dynamic Values { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Deserializing the object is simple:

```cs
Value = model.Values[0].GetDouble();
```

However, I am unable to write to it because `dynamic` is apparently read only:

```cs
model.Values[0] = 1.0;
```

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Property or indexer 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only'

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Deserialize the json as `JObject`.
2. Extract the `jObj["values]` as `JArray`.
3. Update the extracted `JArray` value and assign to `jObj["values"]`.

```cs
JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
JArray values = JArray.Parse(jObj["values"].ToString());
values[0] = 1.0;
jObj["values"] = values;
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/42keEF)

---

Or apply the `Values` property as `List<dynamic>` type or [`ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-6.0) type.

```cs
public class Model
{
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public String Type { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("values")]
    public List<dynamic> Values { get; set; }
    // Or
    // public ArrayList Values { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
Model model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);
model.Values[0] = 1.0;
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KS7ve5)